# Where do I place images on the filesystem for Spring MVC to access?

Tags: spring-mvc

[image]

My spring-servlet.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="org.infopad.controllers"></context:component-scan>

  <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/images/, /static/css/" />

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/"></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
</bean>     
</beans>
```

Where do I place images and css files and how do I access them in a HTML/JSP page?

I am using Spring 3.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your images in `WebContent/static/images/`.

According to your mapping, `WebContent/static/images/somepic.png` can be accessed via url: `YOUR_WEB_CONTEXT/static/somepic.png`

The same is true for css files.